# adding virtual ethernet adapater to a running vm

Tags: centos, vmware-esx, vmware-esxi

VI client doesn't let me add another virtual ethernet adapeter to a centos 5.2 guest vm on ESXi 3.5.

Is there a way to achieve this via some command like tricks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - you cannot hot add Ethernet cards on any version of VMware ESX or ESXi. There isn't any command line way around this on ESX\i 3.5 (or on V4).

Comment: it's coming in 4.whatever for W2K8R2 VMs btw ;)

Comment: Interesting - it's not something I'd have put very high on my list of desired features but clearly there is some demand.